# Retrofit 2.2.0 Android API 24 javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Handshake failed

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2, sslhandshakeexception

I'm using Retrofit 2.2.0 for uploading image to server (using Java). With an Android device (Samsung galaxy S6) API 24 (Build : NRD90M.G920FXXU5EQAC) when I try to post a request, this request failed with this error

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Handshake failed
```

ps: I try to downgrade the Retrofit 2.1.0 and it works perfectly.

Comment: try your url with http not https.

Answer (score 9):

The solution for me was adding more ciphers as acceptable for OkHttpClient. Since API 21, some TLS certificates are deprecated for Android. This might help:

```
ConnectionSpec spec = new 
ConnectionSpec.Builder(ConnectionSpec.MODERN_TLS)
                .tlsVersions(TlsVersion.TLS_1_2)
                .cipherSuites(      
CipherSuite.TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,
CipherSuite.TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,                    
CipherSuite.TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256)
                .build();

OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .connectionSpecs(Collections.singletonList(spec))
            .build();
```

For more info please visit: https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/HTTPS

Answer (score 5):

I have used it with 2.2.0

Create a trust manager that does not validate certificate chains

```
final TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[]{
                new X509TrustManager() {
                    @Override
                    public void checkClientTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void checkServerTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                        return new java.security.cert.X509Certificate[]{};
                   }
                }
        };

        // Install the all-trusting trust manager

        HttpLoggingInterceptor httpLoggingInterceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        httpLoggingInterceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
        OkHttpClient.Builder client = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
        client.interceptors().add(httpLoggingInterceptor);
        client.readTimeout(180, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        client.connectTimeout(180, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
       keyStore.load(null, null);

        SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");

        TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
       trustManagerFactory.init(keyStore);
        KeyManagerFactory keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
        keyManagerFactory.init(keyStore, "keystore_pass".toCharArray());
        sslContext.init(null, trustAllCerts, new SecureRandom());
        client.sslSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory())
                .hostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
                        return true;
                    }
               });

        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setLenient().create();

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(Common.BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .client(client.build())
                .build();

        serviceApi = retrofit.create(Api.class);
```

thanks hope this will help you.
Sometime ssl version 1.2 or lower not installed in server side as well.

Comment: Worked for me, however, I had follow up question. Does this fix means that you could be vulnerable as you would accept any certificate that is sent to the client ?

Comment: what is keystore_pass here?

Comment: Didn't work for me, plus accepting every out there makes the app vulnerable.